# ObjectContext instance has been disposed with Select and ToListAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, async-await

I am trying to use a ToListAsync with some Linq which uses a select to create a list of new objects.

```
        using (dbContext = new MyEntities())
        {
            var listProjectToolFields = await (from pf in dbContext.ProjectToolFields
                join c in dbContext.CustomFields on pf.CustomFieldId equals c.CustomFieldId
                join pt in dbContext.ProjectTools on pf.ProjectToolId equals pt.ProjectToolId
                where pt.ProjectId == projectId && pt.ToolId == toolId && !c.IsDeleted
                select new ProjectToolField
                {
                    ProjectToolFieldId = pf.ProjectToolFieldId,
                    ProjectId = pt.ProjectId,
                    ToolId = pt.ToolId,
                    CustomField = new CustomField
                    {
                        CustomFieldId = c.CustomFieldId,
                        CustomFieldName = c.CustomFieldName,
                        FieldGroupIds = c.FieldGroupIds
                    },
                    SequenceNo = pf.SequenceNo
                }).ToListAsync();
            return listProjectToolFields;
        }
```

The CustomField is just a simple class with auto-implemented properties.

When I get the error it is: The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.

But I am using an await, so how can I overcome this? I really need to use the async, it works without the async/await but I need to change the code to use them.

Comment: Do you get this exception at code mentioned in question, or somewhere else? What is stack trace?

Comment: Where do I find `ToListAsync`? NuGet? Assembly?

Comment: ToLIstAsync is in  System.Data.Entity

Comment: @Evk stack trace is:    at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ReleaseConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.Finally()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper`1.SimpleEnumerator.Dispose()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyAsyncEnumerator`1.Dispose()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.<ForEachAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()

Comment: That's quite strange, because error indicates you dispose context before async enumeration is finished, but in code provided you use "await" with `ToListAsync` so this should not happen. Are you sure that's exact code which throws this exception for you?

Comment: Does it works without async? Try with .ToList() to understand if the problem is elsewhere

Comment: Problem is that you return inside the using in an async function. When you call it, the function returns pretty much a state machine that will execute the ToList operation. But since the async function already returned, the using disposed the context you created inside of it. The operation in the state machine thus fails with ObjectDisposed. [this might give more info on the topic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-829T)

Comment: @sbecker that's just not true. If would be true if there were no `await`. But with `await` it will rewrite method in a way that context will be disposed _after_ `await` completes.

Comment: found the problem; should say  using (var dbContext = new MyEntities()). dbContext was also declared as a private class variable,

Comment: @Evk You're totally right. I think I'm the one who should watch the video in the link I posted.

Comment: @RobSedgwick ah I noticed that but assumed it was just a typo...